# Using Classic Thesis, how to add another section similar to bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, classicthesis

I am using Classic Thesis in Latex. I need to add another section which looks exactly like bibliography but has different data sources. (I am trying to build a "Technical Bibliography" with links to documentations and APIs which don't really fit into Bibliography).

I have been looking around but no success right now.

I have tried adding another FrontBackMatter page and reference it main.tex. I have copied the Bibliography.tex file in it but it seems that the Bibliography is genreated by
 \printBibliography which has a direct reference to the .bib file so that is not of much help.

Thanks !

Comment: You can split a `biblatex` bibliography by type. Or by keywords. This was asked and answered multiple times here and is (probably) unrelated to classicthesis.

Comment: Wouldn't that just compile one bibliography from different datapoints ?

Comment: You would have your normal bibliography, called  Bibliography", and another normal bibliography, called "Technical bibliography". Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Or are you looking for `\chapter{Tech Bib}`? Or `\addchap{Tech Bib}`? It is really not clear from the question.

Comment: I am not looking for the \chapter option. Having "two" bibliographies is what I want. I am looking into how to split biblatex by type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have managed to solve it thanks to Johannes_B (in the comments).

The solution required me to add keywords to the Bibliography and then in the `Bibliography.tex` file:

```
\printbibliography[keyword={tech}, title={Technical Documentation}
\printbibliography[notkeyword{tech}]
```

Thanks again !